# What type of these phone number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me with these phone number, I don't know the reason why I use left to get first number but the result is blank.

[image]

Comment: There may be an invisible character, like a non-breaking space. Can you report back the results of `=CODE(LEFT(B2,1))`

Comment: The result is 63 for all phone above

Comment: Right, so it seems you'll need to do that again but then with `UNICODE` instead as it is no ASCII character apparently.

Answer (score 0):

if all the numbers start with a 0 then you can do something like this:

```
RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(0,A1,1))
```

If you want to get rid of the intermediate space then this may be an option:

```
SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(0,A1,1))," ","")
```